# Beginner VBA for Excel: how can I speed up my code?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on the following VBA code for Excel. It updates a "DATA" sheet of about 12,800 records with fresh information pasted into the sheet "Update2", while retaining any records which an update is not available for. This is for a university department, so its intended use is to be run once or twice a year as a records update.

This currently is taking 2m10s to run, and I'd appreciate any guidance. I've tried a few things (as you can see) but I'm reaching the end of my ability. Thanks.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.StatusBar = "Please wait. Updating records."
    Sheets("Update2").Select
        'The lines below delete the the rows where regnum is zero and the header row.
        On Error Resume Next
        Rows("1:1").Select
            Selection.AutoFilter
                ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$12231").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0"
            Dim LastZero As Long
                LastZero = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    Range("A2:G" & LastZero).Select
                    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$12152").AutoFilter Field:=1
        If Err Then
            'do nothing. This ignores a case where there are no rows where regnum is zero.
        End If
        Range("A1:G1").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Dim LastRow As Long
            LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Range("A1:G" & LastRow).Select
                Selection.Copy
            Sheets("DATA").Select
                Range("A2:G2").Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Columns("A:J").Select
            ActiveSheet.Range("A:J").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
            'This removes duplicate regnums.
            'Unfortunately, this breaks all the formulae. Solutions welcome.
            'What follows is a trudging rewrite of each formula.
        Range("H2").Select
            ActiveCell = "=INDEX($M$2:$M$10, MATCH((LEFT($F2,1)),$L$2:$L$10,0))"
        Range("I2").Select
            ActiveCell = [redacted]
            'An INDEX-MATCH referring to another spreadsheet in the same folder.
            Range("J2").Select
            ActiveCell = "=INDEX(S:S, MATCH($C2,R:R,0))"
        Dim LastData As Long
            LastData = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Range("H2:J2").Copy Range("H2:J" & LastData)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            Application.StatusBar = "Update complete."
```

Comment: Using .Select is the main issue here. You should avoid using select when possible

Comment: I would recommend not applying the auto filter. Even when using excel without running any VBA autofilters slow performance as it's reapplying the filter every time any thing happens

Comment: @Clouse24 I agree, but do you have a suggestion for deleting those entries where column A contains a zero?

Comment: I personally would iterate over the range using a for loop. An example could be similar to this: http://excelerator.solutions/vba-starter-kit/vba-starter-kit-section-5-code-examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One short answer would be to stop using Select and ActiveCell when you can:

Example

```
Range("A1:G1").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Dim LastRow As Long
            LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Range("A1:G" & LastRow).Select
                Selection.Copy
```

Could become

```
Range("A1:G1").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Dim LastRow As Long
            LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Range("A1:G" & LastRow).Copy
```

If you apply this to your whole code, it should get far faster already

For some other examples on how to avoid copy paste for example you can check Ozgrid:
http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)